# Can Images Display the "Open in..." menu on the iPad? How?

Tags: ipad, jpeg

I have a program that opens PDFs.  My program shows up in the "Open In..." menu from emails. However, when I hold down on a picture, the only options that come up are 'Copy' and 'Save Image'.  Is there a way to open an image in another program?